# understanding how class variables are stored in memory in a real situation in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I’m trying to figure out how Vec3b works for Opencv (but I think that it is more a question about basic c++).
The source code is as follows (simplified):

```
template<typename _Tp, int m, int n> class CV_EXPORTS Matx
{
    public:
    // constructors, methods and operators
    ...
        _Tp val[m*n]; //< matrix elements
};


// inherits from Matx
template<typename _Tp, int cn> class CV_EXPORTS Vec : public Matx<_Tp, cn, 1>
{
    public:
    // constructors, methods and operators
    ...
};

typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;
```

For example I can use it to read triplets of BGR (pixels) from an image:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Vec3b* data= (Vec3b*)inputImage.data;
    // access the 10th pixel
    data[10] = Vec3b(0,0,255);
}
```

Tell me if I’ve understood it correctly.
inputImage.data is an array of bytes comprising BGR values and offsets at the end of each row; as val is the only data member of Matx, we can are assured that Vec3b is a set of three bytes and so when I deference the 10th pointer I can access or modify three bytes, starting from the 31st byte.
Just two questions:
1) Why are we sure about the way data are stored in memory? Only because val is the only variable?
2) If 1. is true, don’t you think that it is a dangerous technique, as only adding a second variable would make almost all the code using Vec2b unusable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generally work in practice but there are some potential pitfalls. We can be relatively sure about how data will be laid out in memory because C++ defines fairly specificially the mapping from class definition to memory lay out. Variables will be laided out in memory in the same order they are specified in the class definition, although padding can be inserted between variables to aid alignment. As both items are arrays of the same base type we can be sure that each element is aligned identically. Additionally, the pointer to the first data member will normally be equal to the pointer to the object itself, although I think this is only guaranteed for [plain old data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) types. In practice this will be true for anything that doesn't involve a virtual function.

Ways in which this is dangerous are, as you mention any changes in the member variables of matrix or vec2b would instantly break this. Additionally, adding any virtual methods would break this as the vtable would be added at the start of the object.